# Who has experience of integration GTM ecommerce analytics fot Prestashop

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce, prestashop-1.7

I'm trying to set up ecommerce tracking using Google Tag Manager however I cannot get the data to appear within google analytics?
Use such code in header.tpl

```
{if isset($page_name) && $page_name|escape:'html':'UTF-8' == "order-confirmation"}
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || []
    dataLayer.push({ldelim}
       'transactionId': '{$id_order}',
       'transactionTotal': {$total_paid_tax_incl},
       'transactionProducts': [
       {foreach from=$products item=product}
           {ldelim}                            
           // List of productFieldObjects.
               'sku': '{$product.id}',
               'name': '{$product.name}',     // Name or ID is required.
               //'category': '{$product.X}',
               'price': {$product.price},
               'quantity': 1                        // Optional fields may be omitted or set to empty string.
           {rdelim}
           {if !$smarty.foreach.product.last},{/if}
       {/foreach}
    ]
    {rdelim});
    </script>
```

{/if}

But nothing works

Comment: Is that piece of code ABOVE the GTM snippet?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/mdrtvh

Answer (score 0):

Your datalayer declaration needs to be above the GTM snippet.

Also the noscript part of GTM should be immediately after .

I think you should look through the documentation incase you have other implementation issues:

How to install GTM: https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6103696?hl=en&ref_topic=3441530

Ecommerce with GTM: https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6107169?hl=en

Comment: Put higher but nothing has changed

Comment: Can you provide an example what your code renders out to?

Comment: Then something is wrong with the templating language you're using, you need to fix that first and I'm not familiar with it.